# Integration is not working

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, integral-equations

This integration is not giving an answer. can anyone please help?

```
Integrate[-((0.5 Sqrt[(-0.008 + 0.08 r^2 - 3. r^3 + r^4)/
      r^4] (-0.0000853333 + 0.00128 r^2 - 0.024 r^3 - 0.0170667 r^4 + 
        0.36 r^5 - 6. r^6 + 
        r^7) (0.00188562 Sqrt[2 - 0.016/r^4 + 0.16/r^2 - 6/r] - 
        0.0282843 Sqrt[2 - 0.016/r^4 + 0.16/r^2 - 6/r] r^2 + 
        1.41421 Sqrt[2 - 0.016/r^4 + 0.16/r^2 - 6/r] r^3 - 
        0.707107 Sqrt[2 - 0.016/r^4 + 0.16/r^2 - 6/r] r^4 + 
        1. r^5 Sqrt[(0.00533333 - 0.04 r^2 + r^3)/r^6] Sqrt[(
         0.00533333 - 0.04 r^2 + r^3)/r^4]
          Sqrt[(-0.008 + 0.08 r^2 - 3. r^3 + r^4)/r^4]))/(Sqrt[(
      0.00533333 - 0.04 r^2 + r^3)/
      r^4] (-0.008 + 0.08 r^2 - 3. r^3 + r^4)^3)), {r, 5.93999, mu}, 
 Assumptions -> {mu > 5.94, r > 0}, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

Comment: Why not use `NIntegrate`? `int[mu_] := NIntegrate[expr, {r, 5.93999, mu}];
Plot[int[mu], {mu, 5.9399, 8}]`

Comment: @cvgmt , with NIntegrate it is showing this , NIntegrate::nlim: r = mu is not a valid limit of integration.

Comment: As suggested by @cvgmt, int[mu_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[expr, {r, 5.93999, mu}]; Plot[int[mu], {mu, 5.9399, 8}] produces the result that I presume you wish.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[r_] = -((0.5 Sqrt[(-0.008 + 0.08 r^2 - 3. r^3 + r^4)/
         r^4] (-0.0000853333 + 0.00128 r^2 - 0.024 r^3 - 
         0.0170667 r^4 + 0.36 r^5 - 6. r^6 + 
         r^7) (0.00188562 Sqrt[2 - 0.016/r^4 + 0.16/r^2 - 6/r] - 
         0.0282843 Sqrt[2 - 0.016/r^4 + 0.16/r^2 - 6/r] r^2 + 
         1.41421 Sqrt[2 - 0.016/r^4 + 0.16/r^2 - 6/r] r^3 - 
         0.707107 Sqrt[2 - 0.016/r^4 + 0.16/r^2 - 6/r] r^4 + 
         1. r^5 Sqrt[(0.00533333 - 0.04 r^2 + r^3)/
            r^6] Sqrt[(0.00533333 - 0.04 r^2 + r^3)/
            r^4] Sqrt[(-0.008 + 0.08 r^2 - 3. r^3 + r^4)/
            r^4]))/(Sqrt[(0.00533333 - 0.04 r^2 + r^3)/
         r^4] (-0.008 + 0.08 r^2 - 3. r^3 + r^4)^3));
int[mu_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[r], {r, 5.93999, mu}]
Plot[int[mu], {mu, 5.93999, 8}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Or

```
Clear[F];
F = NDSolveValue[{y'[mu] == f[mu], y[5.93999] == 0},    y, {mu, 5.93999, 8}]; 
Plot[F[mu], {mu, 5.93999, 8}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Comment: Or use `Clear[F];
F = NDSolveValue[{y'[mu] == f[mu], y[5.93999] == 0}, 
  y, {mu, 5.93999, 8}];
Plot[F[mu], {mu, 5.93999, 8}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]`

Comment: Actually, I need the expression in terms of mu as further, I have to integrate with respect to mu after putting this result in some expression.

Comment: @AKU  Use `int[mu]`.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 13 , and using the same way you did, I am getting this error. NIntegrate::nlim: r = mu is not a valid limit of integration.

Comment: it is plotting it but not giving the expression.

Comment: did that too but still not showing the expression. constantly giving NIntegrate::nlim: r = mu is not a valid limit of integration.

Comment: @AKU  There does not seem to be analytical antiderivative. Your only choice is numerical integration. But for this you need to specify a value for the limits including mu.

Comment: @Nasser yes, I have specified mu>4.94 while doing integration but that did not solve the problem. mu is a variable which we can even set r but still no output.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have already numerical values in your expression, you are probably best serve using numerical integration. I'm not sure for what you need the Integration, but for instance you can plot the values using NIntegrate.
Here for example a plot until mu=10:

```
Plot[
 NIntegrate[-((0.5 Sqrt[(-0.008 + 0.08 r^2 - 3. r^3 + r^4)/
         r^4] (-0.0000853333 + 0.00128 r^2 - 0.024 r^3 - 
         0.0170667 r^4 + 0.36 r^5 - 6. r^6 + 
         r^7) (0.00188562 Sqrt[2 - 0.016/r^4 + 0.16/r^2 - 6/r] - 
         0.0282843 Sqrt[2 - 0.016/r^4 + 0.16/r^2 - 6/r] r^2 + 
         1.41421 Sqrt[2 - 0.016/r^4 + 0.16/r^2 - 6/r] r^3 - 
         0.707107 Sqrt[2 - 0.016/r^4 + 0.16/r^2 - 6/r] r^4 + 
         1. r^5 Sqrt[(0.00533333 - 0.04 r^2 + r^3)/
            r^6] Sqrt[(0.00533333 - 0.04 r^2 + r^3)/
            r^4] Sqrt[(-0.008 + 0.08 r^2 - 3. r^3 + r^4)/
            r^4]))/(Sqrt[(0.00533333 - 0.04 r^2 + r^3)/
         r^4] (-0.008 + 0.08 r^2 - 3. r^3 + r^4)^3)), {r, 5.94, mu}],
 {mu, 5.94, 10}
 ]
```

[image: Plot of expression for mu=[5.94,10]]

Comment: Actually, I need the expression in terms of mu as further, I have to integrate with respect to mu after putting this result in some expression.

Comment: Could you post the whole problem, so we can figure out a way around that? With such complicated expressions an analytic workflow is probably not possible, so a numerical approximation of your whole project will be necessary.